# Linear fitting without intercept

Tags: fitting

I want to fit the following model:
$y_t=\beta x_t+\epsilon_t$

For that, I've tried the following

```
In[3]:= Transpose[data]

Out[3]= {{0, 1, 3, 5}, {1, 0, 2, 4}}

In[5]:= LinearModelFit[Transpose[data], IncludeConstantBasis -> False]

During evaluation of In[5]:= LinearModelFit::fitm: Unable to solve for the fit parameters; the design matrix is nonrectangular, non-numerical, or could not be inverted.

Out[5]= LinearModelFit[{{0, 1, 3, 5}, {1, 0, 2, 4}}, 
 IncludeConstantBasis -> False]
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form of `LinearModelFit` that you are trying to use is

```
LinearModelFit[{m, v}]
```

where `m` is a design matrix, and `v` is a response vector. But in your input, `m`, is `{0, 1, 3, 5}`, which is not a matrix. Try this instead:

```
LinearModelFit[{
  {{0}, {1}, {3}, {5}},
  {1, 0, 2, 4}
  },
 IncludeConstantBasis -> False
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you C.E. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Since you have only one paramter, you can use Grid Search method.

$\epsilon_t=y_t-\beta x_t$ and $error=\sum_{i=1}^4(y_i-\beta x_i)^2$.

We see that  $0\leq\beta\leq 1$ from ListPlot.

```
 data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
    ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

```
ϵ[β_] := Total[(#2 - β #1)^2 & @@@ data]
βval = Subdivide[0, 1., 100000];
Extract[βval, Ordering[ϵ[βval], 1]]
```

> 0.74286

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you could use the other structure for `LinearModelFit`:

```
data = Transpose[{{0, 1, 3, 5}, {1, 0, 2, 4}}]
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x, IncludeConstantBasis -> False];
lm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table]